# Вывод и заполнение поле формы по отдельности

Tags: python, django, bootstrap, python-2.x

У меня есть такой вот код, который выводит все поля формы для заполнения:

```
    <fieldset>
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="control-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                <label class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="controls">{{ field }}</div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% csrf_token %}
    </fieldset>
```

Сама форма:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    question = forms.IntegerField()
```

В это форме поле `question` я хотел бы сделать невидимым для пользователя и так, чтобы оно заполнялось автоматически. Как я могу такое сделать ?

Вот моя неудачная попытка:

```
        <fieldset>
            {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.label == 'Question' %}
                    {{ field = question.pk }}
                {% else %}
                    <div class="control-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                        <label class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                        <div class="controls">{{ field }}</div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% csrf_token %}
        </fieldset>
```

Наверняка должно быть готовое решение без таких вот заморочек. Не могу найти в доке.

Comment: Как поле должно автоматически заполняться, на сервере или на клиенте? В какой момент становится возможно подставить значение в question?

Comment: Надо проставить значение в шаблоне.

Comment: Если вам надо сделать поле скрытым, то поможет виджет HiddenInput (question = forms.IntegerField(widget=HiddenInput)) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput Вот в документации пример как итерировать отдельно видимые и скрытые поля https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields Если хотите передать начальные значения для полей, то можно их передать через аргумент initial при создании экземпляра формы https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial

Comment: @Chikiro правильно я понимаю, что в конструктора поля формы необходимо указать `forms.IntegerField(initial='hidden)` ?

Comment: Если вы в классе формы укажете forms.IntegerField(initial='hidden'), то у всех форм, созданных из этого класса начальное значение поля будет строка 'hidden', но такое поле не пройдет валидацию, потому что проверяет значение, приводя его в целое число. Вот так можно передать занчения при создании экземпляра формы f = AnswerForm(initial={'text': 'default text', 'question': 1})